# Python , фреймворк Django

Tags: python, django

Подойдет ли Pycharm community для изучения Django?
Какие учебные материалы могли бы порекомендовать для изучения Django?

Comment: если не путаю то бесплатный Pycharm html не подсвечивает

Comment: не слушай никого, пользуйся тем инструментом которым тебе нравится пользоваться. нет ничего сложного в работе с PyCharm. По поводу учебных материалов, и у PyCharm и у Django есть оф докуметация. У джанго даже туториал есть https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/ И у пайчарма есть встроенный туториал, прямо в редакторе, нажимаешь Learn Pycahrm в окне менеджера проектов и поехали

Answer (score 1):

Я не хочу навязывать своё мнение, но всё таки его выскажу:

Скорее всего, Pycharm будет Вам мешать в изучении Django.

Почему?

Потому, что PyCharm - это мощный и сложный инструмент, котрый сам нуждается в изучении. Когда Вы его выучили - он начинает ускорять вашу работу в разы,но пока не выучили - вы всё время  должны гуглить, как сделать буквально любое действие. Если, конечно, Вы уже не знаете этот инструмент.

Для изучения Django нужна книжка по Django и какой нибудь "легонький" редактор, желательно - с возможностью отладки хотя бы при помощи печати в консоли.

Можно попробовать VS Code, вроде бы её настройка проще, чем PyCharm. Или - пользоваться "голым" питоном и его "родной" "ide" (и я не зря взал это слово в кавычки) IDLE.

Иначе - вам придётся одновременно изучатьдве непростые вещи: Django и среду разработки

В комментариях подсказывают, что в Django есть прекрасная официалоьная документация, что есть [вот такое](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/) руководство с отличным названием "Django Girls" - "Джанго для блондинок" (это литературный перевод). А читать его и правда интересно. Можно читать и мальчикам :-)

Comment: ну еще стоит добавить пару слов про отличную офф документацию, также неплох вот этот туториал  https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/

Comment: с Вашего позволения, я добавлю это в ответ, со ссылкой на Ваш комментарий?

Comment: да конечно, добавляйте